# Order creation via API fails in Magento

Tags: api, magento

I am getting a rather strange error when trying to create a new order via the Magento API V1.0. Here is the basic workflow of my code:

1. Create shopping cart using the `cart.create` method.
2. Set a customer as 'guest' using the `cart_customer.set` method.
3. Add products to cart using the `cart_product.add` method.
4. Create the order using the `cart.order` method.

At this point, the *cart.order* method throws a SoapFault exception with the message "Call to a member function setFinalPrice() on a non-object". The same exception is thrown if I replace the `cart.order` method with other methods such as `cart.info` or `cart_product.list`.

Since the exception's message does not seem very descriptive, I was wondering if anybody else has ever bumped into this.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** The problem is due to the fact that I am adding products to the cart using their SKUs when calling the `cart_product.add` method. The exception is no longer thrown when using product IDs instead of SKUs (I suspect this could be a bug). However, at this point the `cart.order` method returns *false*, so the order is still not created.

Comment: Which magento version do you have? There was an error with ids/sku (when sku is numerical, if i'm not mistaken) in api. It should have been fixed in CE 1.6 / EE 1.11. Before calling `cart.order` you must add customer addresses, set payment and shipping methods. See official [example](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cart#example).

Comment: @Zyava: I can confirm the error is still present in Magento CE 1.6.0.0. Everything works fine when I use IDs instead of SKUs.

Comment: Wait, let's clarify the problem. When you call add to cart with numeric sku: `$proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_product.add", array($shoppingCartId, array("sku" => "111")));` product isn't added to cart?

Answer (score 3):

Before you do cart.order method, you must assign the payment and shipping address to your cart.

*it's standard procedure to create an order in magento.*

the steps should be like this :

- Create shopping cart using the cart.create method.
- Set a customer as 'guest' using the cart_customer.set method.
- Add products to cart using the cart_product.add method.

> try to call 
>   **cart_shipping.method** and **cart_payment.method** before you call **cart.order**

- Create the order using the cart.order method.

Comment: I follow the same process , but it shows me 
"Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1002] Can not make operation because quote is not exists" everytime when i call for cart.create.
I have checked all the calls result before making cart create call and everything is working fine
1)login with api
2) create.cart
3) Setup Customer
4) Setup Address 
5) add products using "cart_product.add"
6) cart_shipping.method
7) ccsave

Comment: I did some tracing and found that quote id is correct , but it is showing inactive in Database table. It is showing 'active' field as 0.

Comment: @p4pravin did you manage to solve this? I'm hitting the same error and the quote id is the correct one

Comment: anyone found a solution for this?